# Using closure library with jsTestDriver

Tags: unit-testing, google-closure-library, js-test-driver

I'm learning about google closure tools by writing a simple JavaScript game. I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up jsTestDriver so that it works well with closure library.

Specifically: I'd like to use the goog.require mechanism to include any additional JavaScript files rather than have to manually add them all to the config file.

Following meyertee's suggestion I made a simple script to automatically write the dependencies to a config file

```
#!/bin/bash
cp tests/jsTestDriver.conf.proto tests/jsTestDriver.conf
libs/closure-library/closure/bin/build/closurebuilder.py --root="./libs/closure-library" --root="./js" --namespace="lds" | sed "s#^#  - \.\./#" >> tests/jsTestDriver.conf
```

The tests/jsTestDriver.conf.proto file is a simple template:

```
test:
  - "*.js"
load:
  - ../libs/knockout-2.1.0.js
# Crucial, the load key needs to be last, and this comment must be followed by a newline.
```

It is a very fragile script, but hopefully someone (other than me) will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, I've changed my project to using the Python scripts too (I'm actually using calcdeps.py). It's better than using the compiler, because it picks up dependencies that aren't linked to your project yet - better for testing new code - and it's faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it semi-automatically by letting Closure Compile generate a manifest file, which will output all files in the correct order of dependency. You can then transform that file to relative paths and paste them into the JsTestDriver config file. That's how I do it.
You could even write a script that does this transformation automatically.

This is the relevant compiler argument:

```
--output_manifest manifest.MF
```

There are some details on the [Closure Compiler's Google Code Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/ManageClosureDependencies)

**Edit:**
There are also some [Python scripts](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder) to help you calculate dependencies. You can use calcdeps.py or closurebuilder.py to generate a manifest file, which even includes files that haven't been 'required' by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since [JsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) does not following the [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) convention of declaring dependencies with `goog.provide()` and `goog.require()`, your best option may be [meyertee's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463018/meyertee) solution.

However, the Closure Library includes its own testing framework. See:

- [Test Driven Development with the Closure Framework](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2074-test-driven-development-with-the-closure-testing-framework/)
- [Asserts API](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/namespace_goog_asserts.html)